# Find the cartesian equation of a plane

Tags: vectors

A line L is given as (9/4,-1/4,0) + $\lambda$(1,3,8). A plane $\pi$ is parallel to both the line L and the line (4,6,2) + $\Phi$(3,-2,0). Given that plane $\pi$ contains the point (1,2,0). Find the Cartesian equation of a plane.

I cant get around the question because the direction vectors of both lines are parallel to the plane and doesn't help me in finding the normal vector of the plane in any way.

Comment: In the future, please try to show some of your own efforts at trying to solve the problem instead of simply pasting in what looks like a homework problem. This isn’t a homework-solving site.

Comment: @amd I am very well aware of that and I did added below my question at what phase I was stuck and somebody edited the post. Go check the unedited post for your satisfaction.

Comment: Yes, that was an overly aggressive edit. I’ve restored your important second paragraph.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**

If the plane is parallel to the lines given by $\vec x = \vec p + \lambda \color{blue}{\vec v}$ and $\vec x = \vec q + \lambda\color{blue}{ \vec w}$, then $\vec n = \color{blue}{\vec v} \times \color{blue}{\vec w}$ is a normal vector of the plane. A Cartesian equation of the plane with normal vector $\vec n = (a,b,c)$ and containing a point $(x_0,y_0,z_0)$ is given by:
$$a\left( x-x_0 \right)+b\left( y-y_0 \right)+c\left( z-z_0 \right)=0$$

Comment: I am under the impression that cross product of two parallel vectors is given by v⃗xw⃗ = v·w sinθ and clearly since the vectors are parallel, the angle they make is 0 degree. Hence cross product comes to 0

Comment: @NipunLamba But the vectors $\vec v$ and $\vec w$ (look at the given equations of the lines) aren't parallel: $(1,3,8) \nparallel (3,-2,0)$... Also if they were, the plane wouldn't be uniquely determined (with the extra point included).

Comment: Lol I feel dumb for making my assumption that the vectors of the two lines are parallel on the fact that if a || b and b ||c, then a || c and I completely didn't see that the vectors of the two lines are not proportionate to each other, hence not parallel. That was really an eye opener for me. Thanks a lot StackTD.

Comment: @NipunLamba Alright, you're welcome!

Comment: @StackTD what would happen if $a$,$b$ or $c$ is 0? Would it still be a cartesian equation of a plane?

Comment: @FredWeasley Yes, that's no problem: they just can't _all (three)_ be zero.

Answer (score 0):

since the plane is parallel to the given straight lines we can compute the plane as $$[x,y,z]=[1;2;0]+s[1;3;8]+t[3;-2;0]$$ where $s,t$ are arbitrary real numbers.
we have the System
$$x=1+s+3t$$
$$y=2+3s-2t$$
$$z=8s$$
multiplying the first equation by $2$ and the second by $3$ then we get
$$2x+3y=8+11s$$ with $$s=\frac{z}{8}$$ we have found the cartesian form as
$$2x+3y-\frac{11}{8}z=8$$

Comment: OP is looking for the cartesian equation of the plane which is of the form $\vec n\cdot \vec x=c$.

Comment: or in the form$$ax+by+cz+d=0$$